# How do you get a Animate.css to work with Tailwind's @responsive directive?

Tags: css, animation, responsive, tailwind-css

I am trying to import a library of CSS classes into the responsive directive.

Animate.css contains a bunch of classes and keyframe animations from https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

The error I get back is: 
 CssSyntaxError: `@apply` cannot be used with `.fadeInRight` because `.fadeInRight` either cannot be found, or its actual definition includes a pseudo-selector like :hover, :active, etc. If you're sure that `.fadeInRight` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed *before* Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.

The end goal is to render a different animation depending on the screen size in a tailwind way.
i.e. 
`<div className="animated tw-fadeInBottom md:tw-fadeInRight faster"></div>`

The css file being built by tailwind looks something like this.

```
@import '../assets/css/Animate.css';

@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;

@responsive {
  .tw-fadeIn {
    @apply fadeIn
  }
}
```

Comment: I mean, it looks like scss runs it though I'm not familiar with tailwinds, but seems like you should be able to swap `@apply` with scss native `@extend` and get the same thing. There's also some special things they have on their installation page docs for scss usage.

Comment: Show `tailwind.config.js` please. Probably, you don't have setting in him.

Comment: module.exports = {
  important: true,
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      display: ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'],
      body: ['Roboto', 'sans-serif'],
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'agility-main': '#16c6ff',
        'agility-main-hover': '#04b2ea',
        'agility-black': '#333',
        'agility-success': '#13997f',
        'agility-background': '#efefef',
        'agility-red-main': '#a51414',
        'agility-red-secondary': '#ff1515',
      },
    },
  },
}

Comment: This is config file. With tailwind, the @apply is a trigger to cause the whatever directive to modify the class you put into it. I tried modifying my css file to an scss file but tailwind didn't apply any responsiveness to the imported css file.

Answer (score 1):

For new users coming here, I have made a simple port of Animate.css that is compatible with TailwindCSS-style [animations](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation), and hence can be directly used by the `@apply`,etc. directives.

Link for docs: https://github.com/ikcb/animated-tailwindcss#readme

#### Basic Usage

To install, run:

```sh
npm i -D animated-tailwindcss
# or
yarn add -D animated-tailwindcss
```

Then just wrap your config with `withAnimations` (and remove import of Animate.css from CSS):

```js
const withAnimations = require('animated-tailwindcss');

module.exports = withAnimations({
  // ... your config here ...
});
```

---

**Other alternatives:** I was able to find out a plugin [`tailwindcss-animatecss`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-animatecss) that does more or less the same thing except for long configuration. But it was available when this question was asked. Strangely no one pointed it out.

---

Now regarding the error you were getting, any class that is used by directives but is neither a part of TW core, nor injected by some plugin/configuration, must be defined under a [`@layer`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer) directive.

So one actually needs to do something like this (if not preferring to use any third-party package):

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  // define your Animate.css classes here
}

// use them here or in your code
```